# ¿Cómo diseño tablas en mysql para gestión de multialmacén?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo que modificar una aplicación **PHP con Mysql**. Se trata de una tienda online y hasta ahora **no tiene multialmacén**.

El stock se guarda en cada artículo/producto *(ec_artículos)*.

Los artículos pueden tener combinaciones *(XL-Verde, XL-Rojo)* o no y éstas se guardan en otra tabla *(ec_combinaciones)*. En la tabla de las combinaciones también se guarda el stock de cada combinación.

Siempre intento simplificar el diseño al más simple y he planificado la estructura nueva en el siguiente dibujo.

[image: Estructura]

Me gustarían vuestras opiniones, ya que debe cubrir todas las expectativas o exigencias que marque el cliente. Luego ya el código en PHP se complicará todo lo necesario.

La idea es **poder gestionar varios almacenes** a través de la tabla *Almacenes*.
Y llevar las existencias hasta la nueva tabla *Tstock*. Aquí le indico por línea el **id del producto**, **id de la combinación** y el **id del almacén**, registrando un stock físico y otro de reserva sobre este *(Para pedidos y albaranes por procesar)*.

Para productos que no tienen combinaciones, *ID_Combinación* en la tabla *Tstock* tendrá valor -1, que corresponde a un registro en blanco y oculto del sistema. De esta manera me aseguro la integridad referencial y puedo borrar en cascada desde las tablas principales.

Y aparte de esta estructura habrá otra tabla que registre los movimientos de almacén, que dejaré en segundo lugar.

¿Os parece correcta la estructura?

Comment: No sé si he entendido bien, pero si una combinación son multiples artículos deberías de tratarlos como artículos. Ya que tendrán su propía id, nombre y precio como el artículo.

Comment: Y así es, par preguntar por una combinación (XL-Verde) tan sólo tengo que preguntar por ID_Combinación, ID_Artículo no me hace falta. Pero a la hora de borrar en cascada sí, si borro un artículo, me borra en cascada sus combinaciones y stock. Esto si lo permito, puedo dar a elegir no borrar nada, según quiera el usuario.

Comment: Bueno, una combinación es sólo un artículo que parte de las permutaciones de Talla y Color por ejemplo. Pero en mi aplicación se pueden añadir multitud de variantes y de ahí salen las combinaciones, por ejemplo Talla+Color+Material y daría por ejemplo: XXL-VERDE-CUERO... XXL-VERDE-POLIPIEL y así sucesivamente, la combinación es realmente 1 prodcto, una vez que el producto tiene combinaciones, todo se basa en esta tabla.

Comment: Entonces te sobraría la relación entre artículos y stock ya que la estás haciendo desde combinaciones.

Comment: No, porque hay artículos que son simples y no tienen combinaciones. Estos artículos no existen en la tabla de combinaciones, de ahí que tenga que tener un id = -1 en la tabla de combinaciones Para cuando añada artículos simples a la tabla de stock

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta tal como está planteada se basa en opiniones. Podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Busco saber si lo que planteo es correcto ya que de errar o ir por un camino equivocado me puede llevar a perder muchos días de trabajo. No sé entonces cómo plantear la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. Esto no es simple de imaginar ni menos de explicar, pero afortunadamente no es un problema nuevo. Antes de seguir, me vas a tener que perdonar pero voy a referirme a las `Combinaciones` como `Variaciones`. Esto porque a la hora de describirlo nos vamos a confundir entre la "combinación" entre dos entidades y una entidad `Combinación` como tal. ¿De acuerdo? Ok, entonces hablemos de `Variaciones`.

A nivel declarativo podemos decir que tu schema indica que

```
Producto `hasMany` Variaciones.
```

Pero como hay una tabla de paso en realidad corresponde decir que la relación es `hasManyThrough`:

```
Producto `hasMany` Variaciones `through` TStock
```

el `Producto` tiene o puede tener muchas `Variaciones` a través de una tabla en donde se declara esa relación.

El modelo, así como está planteado, resulta algo redundante. No pareciera tener sentido usar una tabla de paso si el producto ya está en las variaciones. La misma integridad referencial te indicaría que al borrar un producto se borran sus variaciones, a menos que tú mismo pongas una cláusula ON DELETE SET NULL, y en ese caso dejarías variaciones huérfanas a gusto del usuario. Pero son variaciones a las que ya no podrías aludir... a menos que una variación sea un atributo genérico que puedas poner o quitar de tal o cual producto. Dicho de otra manera, que una `Variación` sea una entidad de primer orden que pueda existir sin un producto.

Es como cuando vas a un lugar de comida rápida y te preguntan "Desea agrandar su coca cola por 1 dolar?". La `Variación` "Agranda Coca cola" se puede aplicar a cualquier combo. Pero no puedes comprar un "Agranda Cola cola" por sí solo. (una vez lo intenté, fuera de broma)

Dejando el tema "Almacenes" de lado, yo enfocaría el problema como una relación entre dos entidades de primer orden. Existen los Productos y existen las Variaciones **como concepto**, luego también es verdad que

```
Variacion `hasMany` Producto `through` TStock
```

**WTF?** Sí, es un poco contraintuitivo, pero si lo pensamos sin restringirnos a la idea de que una Variacion sólo puede pertenecer a un Producto, podemos imaginar el concepto de Variacion como una categorización paralela.

La tabla de paso TStock permite que exista una representación física en donde el `concepto producto` y el `concepto variación` se juntan en un mismo lugar del espaciotiempo y se manifiestan materialmente. Sin un TStock, ambas entidades son sólo formas abstractas de clasificar tu stock.

Dicho de otra manera, si tus productos fuesen

- Camisa
- Pantalón
- Guantes

Y tus atributos

- Manga corta
- Sin dedos
- Media pierna
- Lana
- Modelo Único

La tabla de paso TStock daría lugar a

- Camisa manga corta
- Guantes sin dedos
- Pantalón a media pierna

Y claro, hay variaciones que no aplican a ciertos productos, pero su naturaleza disjunta se manifiesta en que no hay un registro que los asocie en la tabla de paso.

- Si lo enfocamos desde `Producto hasMany Variaciones` tiene todo el sentido que un cliente pregunte "Qué pantalones tiene a la venta?".
- Si lo enfocamos desde `Variacion hasMany Producto`. también tiene todo el sentido que un cliente pregunte: "Qué productos tiene fabricados en lana"?

---

En segundo lugar, si tu lógica exigiera que exista un TStock para mostrar un producto en el listado, puedes tener un atributo genérico que aplica a los productos sin variaciones, y eso me parece mejor que la idea de dejar registros en TStock sin una variación asociada. Digamos que la variación con `id_variacion=1` se llama: "Modelo único". En tu tabla TStock el valor por defecto para `id_variacion` es 1. Luego cuando insertas un producto y omites las variaciones, de cara al usuario es simplemente un producto con modelo único.

A nivel de API una entidad de paso debiese crearse o destruirse en base a las dos entidades de primer orden que está refiriendo. Tú no destruyes productos ni variaciones. Sólo destruyes la manifestación física mediante la cual coincidieron en nuestra realidad. Bueno... si te quieres poner menos espiritual también puedes bajarle el stock a cero y listo.

En un API, dado un producto identificado por  y una variación identificada por , crearías un registro TStock usando un endpoint del tipo

```
PUT producto/<id_producto>/variacion/<id_variacion>
```

Y lo eliminarías mediante

```
DELETE producto/<id_producto>/variacion/<id_variacion>
```

Tú no conoces el `id_stock`. Se genera automáticamente cuando creas una relación - que no existía, y se borra automáticamente cuando eliminas la relación que en buenas cuentas caracterizaba a ese TStock.

---

**Metiendo los almacenes**: una tabla de paso que relacione tres entidades de primer orden es buscarse problemas. Si lo pensamos, no tiene sentido que exista una variación en un almacén si no referencia a un producto. (Por convención dijimos que un producto sin variación en realidad tiene la variación "Modelo Único").

Yo en ese caso crearía una segunda tabla de paso `StockAlmacen` que uniera a TStock con el almacén, y ya que estamos en eso, sería `StockAlmacen` la encargada de decir cuántas unidades físicas de - hay en cierto  puesto que las unidades físicas están en el limbo (o en una bodega secreta) hasta que no se asignan a un almacén, y recién en ese momento decides cuántas vas a asignar a cada almacén.

---

**Otra vuelta de tuerca**

Para tu problema particular, los eCommerce también permiten manejar todo como atributos de producto. Algunos atributos sólo permiten una elección, mientras otros permiten múltiples selecciones, y otros son arreglos asociativos.

```
             __Colores [Rojo, Azul, Verde] (se ofrece en esas variedades)
Producto 1 -|__Tipo [Pantalón] (el atributo Tipo es excluyente)
            |__Stock {Almacén A: 10 un., Almacén B: 5 un.} (Asociativo)
```

Esta última solución nunca me ha gustado porque no tiene una integridad referencial y todo queda desnormalizado en torno al producto. Es el clásico ejemplo de WooCommerce usando la metadata para mezclar peras con manzanas.

He dicho, señoras y señores.

Comment: Pufff.. cuantos datos, voy a estudiar paso a paso todo y mañana voy a sacar conclusiones. Me falta dar más información sobre cómo salen las combinaciones, lo pondré mñn ya que esto ya está desarrollado desde hace años y operativo. Muchas gracias, me has dado información muy relevante que me dará que pensar mucho esta tarde y noche.

Comment: @ManuBurreroSánchez que esté desarrollado hace años y operativo no significa que esté bien planteado. Por la contraparte, algo bien planteado generalmente resulta en darse mil vueltas para llegar a lo mismo que tienes ahora, sólo que con documentación más altisonante.

Comment: @amenadiel +1 La pregunta merece un cierre por *basada en opiniones*, pero la respuesta ... ¡ *chapeau* ! De verdad que me encanta leerte O_O

Answer (score 0):

*No pareciera tener sentido usar una tabla de paso si el producto ya está en las variaciones.*

Cierto, porque cuando vaya a ver el stock de una combinación, no me hace falta el id_producto, pero he puesto los dos para productos sin combinaciones/variaciones

*La misma integridad referencial te indicaría que al borrar un producto se borran sus variaciones, a menos que tú mismo pongas una cláusula ON DELETE SET NULL, y en ese caso dejarías variaciones huérfanas a gusto del usuario.*

En mi caso se borra en cascada al borrar el producto, esto entrará en conflicto con Tstock ya que quiero guardar histórico de movimientos en una tabla aún no panteada: Tstock_movimientos. Pero a unas malas no hago relación y si el id ya no existe puedo mostrar un mensaje en pantalla como hago en los presupuestos y pedidos: “El producto ya no está en la BD”

*Dicho de otra manera, que una Variación sea una entidad de primer orden que pueda existir sin un producto.*

No es posible, todo está relacionado entre EC_articulos<->EC_combinaciones Salvo el id -1 que tengo que crear para cuando los productos no tenga combinación/variación, éste será el valor de id_combinación en la tabla Tstock cuando el producto no tenga combinaciones/variaciones.

*WTF? Sí, es un poco contraintuitivo, pero si lo pensamos sin restringirnos a la idea de que una Variacion sólo puede pertenecer a un Producto, podemos imaginar el concepto de Variacion como una categorización paralela*

**Uff, aquí es donde me pierdo**. Porque la aplicación para ordenación y filtrado tiene multicategorías y taxonomías. Esto lo uso para ordenar, categorizar e identificar productos para los formularios de filtrado y no guarda relación con el stock, precios y demás. Va por otro lado.

*Digamos que la variación con id_variacion=1 se llama: "Modelo único". En tu tabla TStock el valor por defecto para id_variacion es 1. Luego cuando insertas un producto y omites las variaciones, de cara al usuario es simplemente un producto con modelo único.*

Claro, es esto justo lo que quiero hacer o más bien lo que me obliga la estructura, este sería el resultado de la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El registro 4 y 5 tendrían id_combinación = -1

*Yo en ese caso crearía una segunda tabla de paso StockAlmacen que uniera a TStock con el almacén, y ya que estamos en eso, sería StockAlmacen la encargada de decir cuántas unidades físicas de - hay en cierto puesto que las unidades físicas están en el limbo (o en una bodega secreta) hasta que no se asignan a un almacén, y recién en ese momento decides cuántas vas a asignar a cada almacén.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que aquí entre las dos, pero no termino de entender esto.

Ésta es la estructura real de la aplicación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las taxonomías las uso para multitud de módulos que nada tienen que ver con la tienda y de la tabla ec_caracypropi salen las permutaciones de los elementos para crear las combinaciones. Evidentemente si quitas o pones una variación, las combinaciones se borran y crean de nuevo. Por lo tanto todos los ID de combinación cambian. En la imagen se ve que hay los campos de stock están en ambas tablas.

**Lo que no pillo es el porqué de la tabla StockAlmacen y si no es un problema más que una entrada de almacén no se asigne a un almacén y se quede en el limbo ¿Qué ventaja da?**

Answer (score 0):

**Podéis cerrar el tema**

Voy a dejar la estructura de la forma planteada en principio y veré cómo resuelve las necesidades que me vayan pidiendo los clientes.

Os dejo por aquí un ejemplo de la tabla que guardarán los movimientos. En ella se guardan tanto reservas como salidas y entradas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]